# Is it a good user experience for ios to disable back button when a condition becomes true?

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface, ipod

I am just interesting from the point of view of "user experience" is good to disable back button and make to appear another button when some condition becomes true?

Example I have 3 views A, B, C. At the beginning a condition = false.
I go A -> B. I change something in B and the condition becomes true. In this case I would like to disable possibility to return to the view A and enable possibility to go to the view C.

So my question is how I could do it? Hide back button and on this place make appear button, that enables to go to the view C? Or just disable back button and enable button with which
I go to C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a good use for a navigation controller. It's never a good idea to take control away from the user like this. Allow them to cancel their choice in some way. It's also not the correct metaphor for a navigation controller.

One way to do this without navigation controllers is to show some previously hidden control when a choice is made. Look in the Settings app, for example Date and Time, which shows more UI when a choice is made.

Answer (score 1):

As @nevanking said, I too believe that it isn't a good experience for the user, but what if you need it anyhow.

If you're using a `UIButton` with a title like "Back" or in case of your condition "Go to c" then you've to maintain its tag for specific conditions, so in common `IBAction` you can check for the specific condition and do either pop or push. You can do the same even if you're using image for "Back" and "Go to c" option.

```
#define BACK_BUTTON_TAG 1
#define PUSH_BUTTON_TAG 2
```

Do set tag base on your condition, `btn.tag = BACK_BUTTON_TAG;` or `btn.tag = PUSH_BUTTON_TAG;`

```
-(IBAction) doWhatIChoose {
    if(btn.tag == BACK_BUTTON_TAG) {
        //pop to A
    }else{
        //push to C
    }
}
```

Note that, you've to maintain stack of pushed viewcontrolles, from C you have to give user to option of popToRoot (i.e. A) or go back (i.e. B) and have to maintain the buttons state.

Answer (score 1):

No. The user expects buttons to work, and BACK is like a safety net -- it has to be there.

I generally don't like disabled buttons, but if you use them, disabled buttons only make ense when you are going forward, e.g., placing an order, or proceeding through a series.

Note there are some cases where a "back" button could be acceptable in iOS, but never in the top-left. This would only be if you had a custom UI, e.g., a series of dots, and earlier modes would no longer make sense to access.

Comment: thanks a lot, and what about if I push controllers A(animated)->B(not animated)->C(animated), so user has a feeling, that he/she has not been in B. Then by clicking "Back", pop back to B(animated). Is it good or at least acceptable?

Comment: It's hard to answer without knowing exactly what you mean. If you are talking about a "< Back" item on the top left toolbar, then I'd suggest never disabling it. If the UI looks more like a timeline, then what you say might make sense. Sorry I can't say more without knowing what it looks like.

Comment: It could not be "< Back" button. The title could be the title of the view: "< Items". The app will have a menu. One of option of the menu will be "my orders". The idea is when there is no order, go to "Order creation" view. When there are orders go to "Orders overview". But is it a good idea to have a button in the navigation bar to the left, that in both cases will be look like "< Orders overview"?